# PHP Recoverable fatal error - Catch not working

Tags: php, try-catch

I have code that I am trying to update to work with at least PHP version 7.3 and even when I put in a try catch statement I still get a fatal error thrown.

Below is the function that puts Objects into the Session. line causing error: `$objects[$i] = $Object;`

```
function findObjectsLIB() {
        $objects = ""; $i = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION['Objects'] as $o => $Object) {
            $className = get_class($Object);
            if (!empty($className)) {
                try { 
                    $objects[$i] = $Object;
                    $i++;
                } catch(Exception $err) {
                    $_SESSION['errors'] .= $err->getMessage();
                }
            }
        }
        return $objects;
    }
```

I am getting this error.

> PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class Extra could not be
> converted to string.

How it not being caught?

For one it is strange that it is not being caught and why is it having an issue in 7.3 but not 5.6?

Comment: Which line is throwing that error?

Comment: Shouldn't you just declare `$objects = [];` instead of `$objects = "";`?

Comment: This line is throwing the error: $objects[$i] = $Object;

Comment: Definitely follow Chris's advice. In PHP5.6, a variable originally cast as a string could be converted/treated as an array, but that's been fixed since then.

Comment: Chris Haas was right. I didn't even see that I declared it that way. That fixed it.

Comment: To your literal question, there's errors and exceptions. Some errors were converted to exceptions, but if you want most of them you might want to implement your own [error handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57794174/231316)

Comment: You might also want to add an `is_object($Object)` in there. Further, `get_class` cannot return null or anything that would be interpreted as empty, so you can remove most of the guards and keep your loop simple. This might also be a case for `array_filter` instead which some people argue is more readable since it does less, and with PHP 7.4 can be shortened even further. https://3v4l.org/4fRdj